# How to make GAE auto process an action

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

I use GAE and struts. When I input `htpp://localhost:8888`, it will autoload index.jsp.

What I need is for it to process an action immediately.

For example, when I input `htpp://localhost:8888`, it will autoload action "index.a" instead of autoloading the index.jsp page.

I tried using struts without GAE and it worked correctly. But after I added GAE to my project it would't work. What is the problem and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `<welcome-file-list>` to your `web.xml` file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.a</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try this before, but it said

HTTP ERROR 403

Problem accessing /. Reason:

FORBIDDEN